# sklearn PCA number of components_

Tags: scikit-learn, pca

Using sklearn's PCA:

```
m = np.random.randn(10, 5)
mod = PCA()
mod.fit_transform(m)
```

`mod.components_` will have 5 components, which makes sense to me since there are 5 features in the data.

However if `m = np.random.randn(10, 20)`
`mod.components_` will contain 10 components

Assuming the rows in `mod.components_` correspond to the number of features, shouldn't there be 20 components in the second example? Shouldn't there be as many components as features in the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From scikit-learn [PCA](https://ogrisel.github.io/scikit-learn.org/sklearn-tutorial/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)

```
n_components : int, None or string
Number of components to keep. if n_components is not set all components are kept:    
n_components == min(n_samples, n_features)
```

so in first case `min(10,5)=5`, output shape is (5,5) and in second case `min(10,20)=10`, output shape is `(10,20)`

```
from sklearn.decomposition  import *
import numpy as np
m = np.random.randn(10, 5)
mod = PCA()
mod.fit_transform(m)
print(mod.components_.shape) # (5, 5)


m = np.random.randn(10, 20)
mod = PCA()
mod.fit_transform(m)
print(mod.components_.shape) # (10, 20)
```

**Feature Vs Components :**

Suppose you have a dataset, contain 3 Column Named (Age, Sex, Risk_Factor ) and 500 rows. Here, number of features is 3 Not 500. The number of instance/observation/component is 500. How it can be possible every row is a unique feature, rather here, Age, Sex or Risk_Factor is unique feature.
Hope everything is clear.

Comment: Thank you @ashraful. I suppose the question is why are the number of components set to `n_components=min(n_samples, n_features)`? Why isn't `n_components=n_features`? I always thought that there should be as many components as there features...

Comment: I agree that in your 3 column example there are 3 features, and so there should be 3 components. But let's say you have 5 columns instead (Age, Sex, Risk_Factor, Height, Weight) and only 4 observations. Why aren't the number of components 5?

Comment: You have 4 component/observation, but you want to component 5. How can you find an extra  observation, that  is not in your dataset? So it is taken as min(n_samples, n_features) to avoid conflict. hope now it is clear.